# Android Image Width Fill Layout

Tags: android-layout

In an Android activity I want to put a logo to fill the screen horizontally;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="#FF0000"
              android:id="@+id/layout"
>  
    <ImageButton
        android:background="#124644" 
        android:src="@+drawable/androidlogo" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
        android:id="@+id/LogoImage" 
    >
    </ImageButton>  
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textSize="34sp" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:id="@+id/TitleText"
        android:text="Some Test"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
    >
    </TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

In a small screen it fills:

[image: Emulator with MDPI screen]

However not in a large screen:

[image: Emulator with MDPI screen]

I expect setting `layout_width` to `fill_parent` to be sufficient but obviously not. What else must I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using weight and scale type.

This is the modified code... do the chnages according to your need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:background="#FF0000"
              android:id="@+id/layout"
>  
    <ImageButton
        android:background="#124644" 
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
        android:id="@+id/LogoImage"
        android:layout_weight=".8" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    >
    </ImageButton>  
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textSize="34sp" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:id="@+id/TitleText"
        android:text="Some Test"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
    >
    </TextView> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `match_parent` rather than `fill_parent`, because it's deprected. Use also in the element `ImageButton` the attribute `layout_weight` to the element fits the full screen and the `TextView` is visible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/LogoImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="#124644"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/androidlogo" >
    </ImageButton>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some Test"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]